# Task was canceled c#

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Sometimes I get error "Task was canceled". I can not understand how I can identify the problem of an error. As a result, there is little information about the error. I searched for information on many sites, but found nothing. Help me please.

Comment: Did you run it through a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

`Task was canceled` when a TaskCanceledException was thrown while the task is executing.
There are 2 reasons regular:

1. Some code called `Cancel()` bypassing `CancellationTokenSource` associated with the cancellation token before the task completed.
2. The request timed out

So, check your code if there is a calling `Cancel` or recheck your service.

```
    CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = newCancellationTokenSource();    
    CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;    
    tokenSource.Cancel();    
    Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello"), token);
```